# Array function with implies arrow at center

Tags: amsmath, arrows, overleaf, arrays, cases

I want to display multiple functions in an array with an implies arrow next to it in the center.

```
\begin{equation*}
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
  \left\{
  \begin{array}{ c c }
    \varphi \left(\sigma\right)=1\\
    \varphi \left(\tau \right)=0 
  \end{array}
  \right.
\end{equation*}
```

This is my attempt.

[image]

This is what i want it to look like

[image]

Or if it cant be fit in one line then like this

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With use of `align` and `aligned` environments:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    \left\{\begin{aligned}
\varphi(\sigma) & =1\\
\varphi(\tau)   & =0
    \end{aligned}\right.
    \Rightarrow N=\langle \sigma^2,\tau\rangle
    &&
     \left\{\begin{aligned}
\varphi(\sigma) & =0\\
\varphi(\tau)   & =1
    \end{aligned}\right.
    \Rightarrow N=\langle \sigma\rangle
    &&
    \left\{\begin{aligned}
\varphi(\sigma) & =1\\
\varphi(\tau)   & =1
    \end{aligned}\right.
    \Rightarrow N=\langle \sigma^2,\tau\sigma\rangle
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect, thank you!!!